# HTML Dropdown Menu not working

Tags: html, css

I am working on this website http://www.aoaluminiumproducts.com.au/, and i cant seem to get the drop-down working. I would like the "Services" tab to be a drop-down item with the sub nav 1 links etc (I will change the names).

**HTML/CSS SOURCE**

```
<div id="menubar">
<ul id="menu"><!-- put class="selected" in the li tag for the selected page - to highlight which page you're on -->
<li class="selected"><a href="index.html">Home</a>
<div class="c1"></div>
</li>
<li><a href="services.html">Our Services</a></li>

<ul>
                        <li><a href="#" title="Sub Nav Link 1">Sub Nav Link 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" title="Sub Nav Link 2">Sub Nav Link 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" title="Sub Nav Link 3">Sub Nav Link 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" title="Sub Nav Link 4">Sub Nav Link 4</a></li>

                    </ul>  


<li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

html
{ height: 100%;}

*
{ margin: 0;
  padding: 0;}

body
{ font: 0.8em/1.5 "arial",sans-serif; 
  color: #303030;
  background: #990000;
  }

p
{ padding: 0 0 20px 0;
  line-height: 1.7em;}

img
{ border: 0;}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 
{ font: normal 175% 'century gothic', arial, sans-serif;
  color: #43423F;
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
  padding: 15px 0 5px 0;}

h2
{ font: normal 200% 'century gothic', arial, sans-serif;
  color: #1293EE;}

h4, h5, h6
{ margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 5px 0;
  font: normal 120% arial, sans-serif;
  color: #1293EE;}

h5, h6
{ font: italic 95% arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 0 0 15px 0;
  color: #000;}

h6
{ color: #362C20;}

a, a:hover
{ outline: none;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #CC0000;}

a:hover
{ text-decoration: none;}

.left
{ float: left;
  width: auto;
  margin-right: 10px;}

.right
{ float: right; 
  width: auto;
  margin-left: 10px;}

.center
{ display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px auto;}

blockquote
{ margin: 20px 0; 
  padding: 10px 20px 0 20px;
  border: 1px solid #E5E5DB;
  background: #FFF;}

ul
{ margin: 2px 0 22px 17px;}

ul li
{ list-style-type: circle;
  margin: 0 0 6px 0; 
  padding: 0 0 4px 5px;}

ol
{ margin: 8px 0 22px 20px;}

ol li
{ margin: 0 0 11px 0;}

#main, #logo, #menubar, #site_content, #footer
{ margin-left: auto; 
  margin-right: auto;}

#header
{ background: #990000;
  height: 240px;}

#logo
{ width: 810px;
  position: relative;
  height: 120px;
  background: #150517; url(logo.png) no-repeat;}

#logo #logo_text 
{ position: center; 
  top: 20px;
  left: 0;}

#logo h1, #logo h2
{ font: normal 300% 'century gothic', arial, sans-serif;
  border-bottom: 0;
  text-transform: none;
  margin: 0;}

#logo_text h1, #logo_text h1 a, #logo_text h1 a:hover 
{ padding: 22px 0 0 0;
  color: #FFF;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  text-decoration: none;}

#logo_text h1 a .logo_colour
{ color: #FAF700;}

#logo_text h2
{ font-size: 100%;
  padding: 4px 0 0 0;
  color: #DDD;}

#menubar
{ width: 877px;
  height: 72px;
  padding: 0;
  background: #150517; url(menu.png) repeat-x;
  } 

ul#menu, ul#menu li
{ float: left;
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0;}

ul#menu li
{ list-style: none;}

ul#menu li a
{ letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  font: normal 100% 'lucida sans unicode', arial, sans-serif;
  display: block; 
  float: left; 
  height: 37px;
  padding: 29px 26px 6px 26px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: transparent;} 

ul#menu li a:hover, ul#menu li.selected a, ul#menu li.selected a:hover
{ color: #FFF;
  background: #451C1B url(menu_select.png) repeat-x;}

#site_content
{ width: 900px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  padding: 20px 24px 20px 37px;
  background: #DCDCDC;} 

.sidebar
{ float: right;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 0 15px 20px 15px;}

.sidebar ul
{ width: 178px; 
  padding: 4px 0 0 0; 
  margin: 4px 0 30px 0;}

.sidebar li
{ list-style: none; 
  padding: 0 0 7px 0; }

.sidebar li a, .sidebar li a:hover
{ padding: 0 0 0 40px;
  display: block;
  background: transparent url(link.png) no-repeat left center;} 

.sidebar li a.selected
{ color: #444;
  text-decoration: none;} 

#content
{ text-align: left;
  width: 595px;
  padding: 0;}

#content ul
{ margin: 2px 0 22px 0px;}

#content ul li
{ list-style-type: none;
  background: url(bullet.png) no-repeat;
  margin: 0 0 6px 0; 
  padding: 0 0 4px 25px;
  line-height: 1.5em;}

#footer
{ width: 878px;
  font: normal 100% 'lucida sans unicode', arial, sans-serif;
  height: 33px;
  padding: 24px 0 5px 0;
  text-align: center; 
  background: #000000;
  color: #b1b1b1;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;}

#footer a
{ color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;}

#footer a:hover
{ color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: underline;}

.search
{ color: #5D5D5D; 
  border: 1px solid #BBB; 
  width: 134px; 
  padding: 4px; 
  font: 100% arial, sans-serif;}

#colours
{ height: 0px;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 66px 16px 0px 300px;}

.form_settings
{ margin: 15px 0 0 0;}

.form_settings p
{ padding: 0 0 4px 0;}

.form_settings span
{ float: left; 
  width: 200px; 
  text-align: left;}

.form_settings input, .form_settings textarea
{ padding: 5px; 
  width: 299px; 
  font: 100% arial; 
  border: 1px solid #E5E5DB; 
  background: #FFF; 
  color: #47433F;}

.form_settings .submit
{ font: 100% arial; 
  border: 1px solid; 
  width: 99px; 
  margin: 0 0 0 212px; 
  height: 33px;
  padding: 2px 0 3px 0;
  cursor: pointer; 
  background: #7D0F0F; 
  color: #FFF;}

.form_settings textarea, .form_settings select
{ font: 100% arial; 
  width: 299px;}

.form_settings select
{ width: 310px;}

.form_settings .checkbox
{ margin: 4px 0; 
  padding: 0; 
  width: 14px;
  border: 0;
  background: none;}

.separator
{ width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #D9D5CF;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;}

table
{ margin: 10px 0 30px 0;}

table tr th, table tr td
{ background: #DCDCDC;
  color: #DCDCDC;
  padding: 7px 4px;
  text-align: left;}

table tr td
{ background: #DCDCDC;
  color: #DCDCDC;
}

#testimonials{
    width: 133px;
    padding: 45px 45px 35px;
    background:url('../img/quotes.png') no-repeat 20px 20px rgba(178,178,169,0.2);
    min-height:90px;

    -moz-border-radius:12px;
    -webkit-border-radius:12px;
    border-radius:12px;
}
#testimonials ul{ list-style:none;}
#testimonials p.text{ font-size:11px;}

#testimonials p.author{
    color: #878787;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: left;

}

#testimonials p.author a,
#testimonials p.author a:visited{
    color:#6aa42a;
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason you're reinventing the wheel? The CSS dropdown menu has been done to death already.

Answer (score 1):

See the fiddle with solved issue: If i am getting your problem correct then this might be your solution

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tDAAs/1/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tDAAs/1/embedded/result/

Comment: Thanks so much for the code Singh, it works perfect. Just one some problem, when you go to http://www.aoaluminiumproducts.com.au/index.html the hover goes up the top, but in your example its perfect when down bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the `hover` for the `ul` element, only for the `ul a`

using your html, you need to have the following css:

```
ul#menu ul#sub-menu {
display: none;
}

ul#menu ul#sub-menu:hover {
display: inline-block;  // or display:inline if you want them horizontally positioned
}
```

add the `id=sub-menu` or whatever you want to label it as, to the html element and it should work ok then.

Comment: thanks for the code update :) I have added the above css code and I placed id=sub-menu on the services ul element but its not showing. Any suggestions? Or did i place it on the wrong element?

Answer (score -1):

Ok, try this:

HTML:

```
<div id="menubar">
<ul id="menu">
<li class="selected"><a href="index.html">Home</a>
<div class="c1"></div>
</li>
<li><a href="services.html">Our Services</a>
// Take out the <li> from the submenu and add a span

    <span><a href="#" title="Sub Nav Link 1">Sub Nav Link 1</a></span>
    <span><a href="#" title="Sub Nav Link 2">Sub Nav Link 2</a></span>
    <span><a href="#" title="Sub Nav Link 3">Sub Nav Link 3</a></span>
    <span><a href="#" title="Sub Nav Link 4">Sub Nav Link 4</a></span>
</li>
<li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

The CSS:

```
ul#menu {
list-style: none;
position: relative;
.. // other styling you want like color, font spacing etc.
}
ul#menu li {
float: left;
.. // other styling like border, text color, etc.
}

ul#menu li a {
display: inline;  // you have the menu running horiz on your page
.. // other stylings
}

ul#menu li span {
float: left;
position: absolute;
display: none;
}

ul#menu li:hover span {
display: block; // list submenu vertically
}
```

I haven't tested this but it should be close to what you need.